# Is a C++ MFC program fully native?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I'm looking to create a windows program that doesn't require any environmental dependencies (like Java JRE or .NET).  I need the program to just install out of the box and work on any version of windows between 95 and 7.

Is creating it with C++ and MFC the way to go?

Thanks,

Comment: That will certainly create a "pure windows" binary, yes.

Comment: I don't think native code means what you think it means.

Comment: I believe the most recent compiler (from Microsoft) that produced output that would work on Windows 95 was VC++6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's "native", but that doesn't mean you won't have dependencies (which I think is what you're asking about).

If you dynamicly link with MFC you'll have a dependency on MFC that you will have to [redistribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You could link statically with the MFC library, in which case all the object code needed is included in your executable. But [linking statically is not recommended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235316.aspx) (one reason is for security - security updates to MFC can't get pushed out to your application unless you do it).

Comment: Thank you, if understand this correctly I can create an installer for the program and the necessary files will be bundled together.  What I meant by a dependency was more of an environment that would require changes to the registry, services, etc.  Which for the client is completely out of the question.

Please excuse by ignorance on the topic and my misuse of terms.